# Close DropDown Menu after clicking a link (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want the DropMenu (in mobile query) to close after clicking a link in the menu, and also that the icon stay in his position and not to move below the list of li.

This is my HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<a id="icono" href="http://www.facebook.com/clenslimpieza" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa facebook fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="dropdownClick">
  <li><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#quees">¿Qué es?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#porque">¿Por qué?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#servicios">Servicios</a></li>
  <li><a href="#testimonios">Testimonios</a></li>
  <li><a href="#equipo">Equipo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contactenos">Contactenos</a></li>
  <li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" 
  onclick="dropdownMenu()"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
  </i></a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the Script code:

```
<script>
function dropdownMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
  if (x.className === "nav navbar-nav") {
    x.className += "responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav navbar-nav";
  }
};
</script>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px ) {
#equipo {
 height: auto;
}

.navbar-nav li:not(:nth-child(8)) {
 display: none;
} 

ul.nav li.dropdownIcon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

ul.nav.responsive li.dropdownIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

ul.nav.responsive {
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav.responsive li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}

ul.nav.responsive li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one option!

```js
function dropdownMenu() {
var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
if (x.className === "nav navbar-nav") {
  x.className += "responsive";
} else {
  x.className = "nav navbar-nav";
}


 }
 $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").prev().dropdown("toggle");
});
 $('#dropdownClick li a').click(function(){
 $(this).closest('nav.navbar').find('.navbar-navresponsive').addClass('nav navbar-nav').toggleClass('navbar-navresponsive');
})
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px ) {
#equipo {
 height: auto;
}

.navbar-nav li:not(:nth-child(8)) {
 display: none;
} 

ul.nav li.dropdownIcon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

ul.nav.responsive li.dropdownIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

ul.nav.responsive {
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav.responsive li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}

ul.nav.responsive li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<a id="icono" href="http://www.facebook.com/clenslimpieza" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa facebook fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<ul class="pull-right">
<li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" 
  onclick="dropdownMenu()"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
  </i></a></li></ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="dropdownClick">
  <li><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#quees">¿Qué es?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#porque">¿Por qué?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#servicios">Servicios</a></li>
  <li><a href="#testimonios">Testimonios</a></li>
  <li><a href="#equipo">Equipo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contactenos">Contactenos</a></li>
  
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the position, but you know how to close the dropdown when i click a list item?

Comment: I made some changes, check it out.